# Is std::free thread-safe?

Tags: c++, g++, thread-safety

According to cppreference.com, `std::malloc` is thread-safe, but it doesn't say anything about `std::free`.

Is it thread-safe in Gnu C++ compilier?

I need this because I use libjpeg from C++.

Comment: Does it matter?  Calling `std::free` twice on the same resource will give you a segfault anyway, no matter which order the calls occur in.  It only works in conjunction with setting the freed resource to `nullptr` afterwards but then you need a mutex anyway for the write.

Comment: std::free is called for different pointers. One process calls std::free(x), while another one calls std::free(y) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes,`std::free` is thread-safe. From [[new.delete.dataraces]p1](https://wg21.link/new.delete.dataraces#1):

> For purposes of determining the existence of data races, [...] the C standard library function `free` [...] shall not introduce a data race ([[res.on.data.races]](https://wg21.link/res.on.data.races)).